# bucket4j redisson spring Java17: error JCacheProxyManager ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class [B ... loader bootstrap

Tags: spring-boot, java-17, redisson, jcache, bucket4j

Getting the following error trying to use bucket4j API for Bucket.tryConsume when using:
`bucket4j + JCache + redisson + springboot + Java17`

**pom.xml**

```
<!-- Bucket4J starter : Bucket4J + JCache -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.giffing.bucket4j.spring.boot.starter</groupId>
    <artifactId>bucket4j-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.1</version>
    <exclusions> <!-- EXCLUDE ehcache -->
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<!-- REDIS redisson for cache cli -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
    <artifactId>redisson-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.23.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**Error:**
on redisson JCache invoke:

```
io.github.bucket4j.distributed.proxy.DefaultBucketProxy@789e42d1
javax.cache.processor.EntryProcessorException: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class [B (java.lang.String and [B are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.redisson.jcache.JCache.invoke(JCache.java:3067)
    at io.github.bucket4j.grid.jcache.JCacheProxyManager.execute(JCacheProxyManager.java:82)
    at io.github.bucket4j.distributed.proxy.AbstractProxyManager$DefaultRemoteBucketBuilder$1.execute(AbstractProxyManager.java:197)
    at io.github.bucket4j.distributed.proxy.DefaultBucketProxy.execute(DefaultBucketProxy.java:208)
    at io.github.bucket4j.distributed.proxy.DefaultBucketProxy.consumeAsMuchAsPossibleImpl(DefaultBucketProxy.java:78)
    at io.github.bucket4j.AbstractBucket.tryConsumeAsMuchAsPossible(AbstractBucket.java:307)
```

**Caused by:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class [B (java.lang.String and [B are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at io.github.bucket4j.grid.jcache.JCacheProxyManager$JCacheTransaction.getRawState(JCacheProxyManager.java:188)
    at io.github.bucket4j.distributed.remote.AbstractBinaryTransaction.get(AbstractBinaryTransaction.java:72)
    at io.github.bucket4j.distributed.remote.commands.ConsumeAsMuchAsPossibleCommand.execute(ConsumeAsMuchAsPossibleCommand.java:109)
    at io.github.bucket4j.distributed.remote.AbstractBinaryTransaction.execute(AbstractBinaryTransaction.java:53)
    at io.github.bucket4j.grid.jcache.JCacheProxyManager$BucketProcessor.process(JCacheProxyManager.java:167)
    at io.github.bucket4j.grid.jcache.JCacheProxyManager$BucketProcessor.process(JCacheProxyManager.java:155)
    at org.redisson.jcache.JCache.invoke(JCache.java:3055)
```

calling bucket4j Bucket API : bucket.tryConsumeAsMuchAsPossible(n);

expected to succeed, but getting the error mentioned above instead.

Answer (score 0):

**#1**
noted from https://github.com/MarcGiffing/bucket4j-spring-boot-starter
that I should have used **version 0.8.1 of bucket4j-spring-boot-starter** :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.giffing.bucket4j.spring.boot.starter</groupId>
    <artifactId>bucket4j-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <!-- https://github.com/MarcGiffing/bucket4j-spring-boot-starter -->
    <version>0.8.1</version> <!-- use 0.8.* gives you Bucket4j 8.1.0 & works with Spring Boot 2.7.x -->
    <exclusions> <!-- EXCLUDE ehcache -->
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

as 0.8.* gives you Bucket4j 8.1.0 & works with Spring Boot 2.7.x (which is the spring version I had)

**#2**
found that I had the following **codec** used in my redisson config yaml which was not correct for my use case:

```
codec: !<org.redisson.codec.JsonJacksonCodec> {}
```

removed this and now able to see at least the basic functionality working.

will proceed to testing the clustered redis deployment with bucket4j springboot starter 0.8.1 next.